# The most frequent item of an array using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm looking for some help about an exercise where I have to return the item with the maximum occurrences in an array. I know there are other posts about this, but I can't find one which uses *lodash* only that I succeed to adapt.

For example :

`var array = [3, 'a', 'a', 'a', 2, 3, 'a', 3, 'a', 2, 4, 9, 3]`

*Should return : a (5times)*

I tried with methods like `._groupBy`, `._countBy`, `_.sortBy` but I always find myself stuck at some point. Thanks.

Comment: _“I tried with methods like `_.groupBy`, `_.countBy`, `_.sortBy`”_ — Can we please see those attempts? Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE! This question asks for lodash and the dupe question is for underscore! Not the same!

Comment: Great question. And your question being attacked seems to be another great example of peons projecting their delusions of self-importance via social media `gatekeeping`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [`_.countBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#countBy) to get an object of element:count. Convert to an array of tuples using [`_.entries()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#toPairs). Find the max with [`_.maxBy(_.last)`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#maxBy), since the count value is the 2nd item in the tuple. Extract the element from the tuple using [`_.head()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#head).

```js
var array = [3, 'a', 'a', 'a', 2, 3, 'a', 3, 'a', 2, 4, 9, 3];

var result = _.head(_(array)
  .countBy()
  .entries()
  .maxBy(_.last));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

And if you are importing specific methods from lodash, and don't want to use a chain use [`_.flow()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#flow) instead:

```js
var { countBy, entries, flow, head, last, maxBy, partialRight } = _;

var array = [3, 'a', 'a', 'a', 2, 3, 'a', 3, 'a', 2, 4, 9, 3];

var result = flow(
  countBy,
  entries,
  partialRight(maxBy, last),
  head
)(array);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```